# If the Discovery contains an experimental spore drive, why doesn't it have a NX registry?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, spore-drive

In [Star Trek Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery) [S1:E3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings) *Context is for Kings* the protagonist [Michael Burnham](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Burnham) joins the [USS Discovery](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Discovery). She finds that the ship has an experimental [Spore Drive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spore_drive).

We know that The Federation used the [NX prefix](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/NX) for [experimental ships](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prototype).

But the Discovery's ship number is [NCC-1031](http://ncc-1031.com/starships/star-trek-discovery-uss-discovery-ncc-1031/).

Indeed, the following commentator [writes](https://twitter.com/raymond_tim/status/917654311546576896):

> Shouldn't the Discovery have an NX prefix, since it's an experimental vessel, with a spore drive?

My question is: **If the Discovery contains an experimental spore drive, why doesn't it a NX registry?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The NX registry designation was used for **experimental starship designs**, basically a **starship class prototype**, not for ships that were used to test **experimental technologies**.

In other words, the NX meant that the whole new ship model was under test, not the single technologies that it carried on board; and the premise that the Discovery is an experimental ship, instead of a ship used for testing experimental technologies, is wrong and not supported by any evidence.

There is no indication that the *USS Discovery* was the first ship of its class and therefore considered to be a prototype (so being registered with a NX designation), as a matter of fact we have some clues that imply the contrary:

- we know that the *[USS Discovery](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Discovery)* registry number is *NCC-1031*, while its sister ship, the *[USS Glenn](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Glenn)*, had *NCC-1030*; this implies that the Glenn was launched before the Discovery; this eliminates every chance that that Discovery was the first of its class;
- we also know that both these vessels were *[Crossfield-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Crossfield_class)* starships; there are many examples where the class name was also the name of the first ship of that class (Excelsior, Galaxy, Prometheus, Defiant); so we can safely assume that the first ship and prototype belonging to the *Crossfield-class* was the hypothetical *USS Crossfield*, that would have been the ship to be registered with a NX designation.

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but the Wiki says "Discovery was actually built from the ground up to be a testbed for the experimental spore drive" which certainly *sounds* like an NX-class design.  Is the Wiki wrong about this?

Comment: A ship being built to serve as the main test place for a new tech does not necessarily mean that the ship itself should be a new design.

Answer (score 15):

From your third link ([USS Discovery](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Discovery)):

> Due to the outbreak of the Federation-Klingon War of 2256, a vessel as new as Discovery would normally have been pressed into service on the front lines, even though it would have a relatively small impact compared to other, more combat-oriented vessels. Instead, Discovery was placed under the command of Captain Lorca and **given a clandestine mission** to conduct black ops scientific research, developing top-secret weapons and technologies that would help the Federation win the war.

(Emphasis mine.)  Using the NX prefix would have represented an unacceptable security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Discovery is not an experimental starship in the sense that it was chosen first hand for development of the drive. The NX designation is used for the Lead ship; the first of it's type, then NCC follows it's sister ships (Crossfield, Glenn, Discovery)
Examples USS Defiant: NX-74205, USS Prometheus: NX-74913